# Using spread with duplicate identifiers for rows

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyr

I have a long form dataframe that have multiple entries for same date and person.

```
jj <- data.frame(month=rep(1:3,4),
             student=rep(c("Amy", "Bob"), each=6),
             A=c(9, 7, 6, 8, 6, 9, 3, 2, 1, 5, 6, 5),
             B=c(6, 7, 8, 5, 6, 7, 5, 4, 6, 3, 1, 5))
```

I want to convert it to wide form and make it like this:

```
month Amy.A Bob.A Amy.B Bob.B
1     
2     
3
1
2
3
1
2
3
1
2
3
```

My question is very similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30592094/r-spreading-multiple-columns-with-tidyr). I have used the given code in the answer :

```
kk <- jj %>% 
  gather(variable, value, -(month:student)) %>% 
  unite(temp, student, variable) %>% 
  spread(temp, value)
```

but it gives following error:

> Error: Duplicate identifiers for rows (1, 4), (2, 5), (3, 6), (13, 16), (14, 17), (15, 18), (7, 10), (8, 11), (9, 12), (19, 22), (20, 23), (21, 24)

Thanks in advance.
Note: I don't want to delete multiple entries.

Comment: The output doesn't make sense. How is Bob.B `5 6 7`. There are two Bob B values for month 1,  `5 3`? And for month 2 it is `4 and 2`. Finally, for month 3 `6 5`. You are summarizing these to one value.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The issue is the two columns for both `A` and `B`. If we can make that one value column, we can spread the data as you would like. Take a look at the output for `jj_melt` when you use the code below.

```
library(reshape2)
jj_melt <- melt(jj, id=c("month", "student"))
jj_spread <- dcast(jj_melt, month ~ student + variable, value.var="value", fun=sum)
#   month Amy_A Amy_B Bob_A Bob_B
# 1     1    17    11     8     8
# 2     2    13    13     8     5
# 3     3    15    15     6    11
```

I won't mark this as a duplicate since the other question did not summarize by `sum`, but the `data.table` answer could help with one additional argument, `fun=sum`:

```
library(data.table)
dcast(setDT(jj), month ~ student, value.var=c("A", "B"), fun=sum)
#    month A_sum_Amy A_sum_Bob B_sum_Amy B_sum_Bob
# 1:     1        17         8        11         8
# 2:     2        13         8        13         5
# 3:     3        15         6        15        11
```

If you would like to use the `tidyr` solution, combine it with `dcast` to summarize by `sum`.

```
as.data.frame(jj)
library(tidyr)
jj %>% 
  gather(variable, value, -(month:student)) %>%
  unite(temp, student, variable) %>%
  dcast(month ~ temp, fun=sum)
#   month Amy_A Amy_B Bob_A Bob_B
# 1     1    17    11     8     8
# 2     2    13    13     8     5
# 3     3    15    15     6    11
```

**Edit**

Based on your new requirements, I have added an activity column.

```
library(dplyr)
jj %>% group_by(month, student) %>% 
  mutate(id=1:n()) %>%
  melt(id=c("month", "id", "student")) %>%
  dcast(... ~ student + variable, value.var="value")
#   month id Amy_A Amy_B Bob_A Bob_B
# 1     1  1     9     6     3     5
# 2     1  2     8     5     5     3
# 3     2  1     7     7     2     4
# 4     2  2     6     6     6     1
# 5     3  1     6     8     1     6
# 6     3  2     9     7     5     5
```

The other solutions can also be used. Here I added an optional expression to arrange the final output by activity number:

```
library(tidyr)
jj %>% 
  gather(variable, value, -(month:student)) %>%
  unite(temp, student, variable) %>%
  group_by(temp) %>%
  mutate(id=1:n()) %>%
  dcast(... ~ temp) %>%
  arrange(id)
#   month id Amy_A Amy_B Bob_A Bob_B
# 1     1  1     9     6     3     5
# 2     2  2     7     7     2     4
# 3     3  3     6     8     1     6
# 4     1  4     8     5     5     3
# 5     2  5     6     6     6     1
# 6     3  6     9     7     5     5
```

The `data.table` syntax is compact because it allows for multiple `value.var` columns and will take care of the spread for us. We can then skip the `melt -> cast` process.

```
library(data.table)
setDT(jj)[, activityID := rowid(student)]
dcast(jj, ... ~ student, value.var=c("A", "B"))
#    month activityID A_Amy A_Bob B_Amy B_Bob
# 1:     1          1     9     3     6     5
# 2:     1          4     8     5     5     3
# 3:     2          2     7     2     7     4
# 4:     2          5     6     6     6     1
# 5:     3          3     6     1     8     6
# 6:     3          6     9     5     7     5
```

Comment: Thanks for answering. I do  not want to sum. No arithmatical operation is needed. I want to create A and B columns for  Amy,  and A and B columns for  Bob that simply have thier respective values.

Comment: If there are two values for the same month, student, and class, which one would you like to pick?

Comment: I want both. Actually I am dealing with bid and ask data and hence there are multiple entries.

Comment: So you are not summarizing by the variables in question. You want a new variable that can act as an activity id. Also, do not use code snippets in your question. They do not work and the output is jumbled. Just highlight your code, paste, highlight and use Ctrl+K to indent into code readable format.

Comment: May be a new activity id vairable do the job. I have no idea. It would be  very kind of you if you can go through the linked question I posted in the question. My output should be same. The only difference is duplicate date rows for the same person with different values in all other columns.

Comment: Thank you very much. Would you please explain the tidyr code specially dcast(...~ temp) part?

Comment: We could have used `dcast(month + id ~ temp, value.var="value")`. We used a few tricks to shorten it. The three dots (all other columns) made it so that we would not have to write `month + id` and we did not have to write `value.var="value"` because the function will guess the value column by using the last column.

Answer (score 29):

Your answer was missing mutate id! Here is the solution using dplyr packge only.

```
jj %>% 
  gather(variable, value, -(month:student)) %>% 
  unite(temp, student, variable) %>% 
  group_by(temp) %>% 
  mutate(id=1:n()) %>% 
  spread(temp, value) 
#  A tibble: 6 x 6
#  month    id Amy_A Amy_B Bob_A Bob_B
# * <int> <int> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
# 1     1     1     9     6     3     5
# 2     1     4     8     5     5     3
# 3     2     2     7     7     2     4
# 4     2     5     6     6     6     1
# 5     3     3     6     8     1     6
# 6     3     6     9     7     5     5
```

Comment: If you don't want the *id* column, just add `%>% select(-id)` at the end.

Comment: This is a good trick. To expand briefly: if you don't have a unique id for each row before gather, there is no way to determine which values belong with which observations when spreading. Adding any columns that acts as a primary key mitigates this.

Comment: This doesn't use `dplyr` only: `gather`, `unite`, and `spread` are all from `tidyr`

Answer (score 2):

Since *tidyr 1.0.0* `pivot_wider` is the recommended replacement of `spread` and you could do the following :

```r
jj <- data.frame(month=rep(1:3,4),
                 student=rep(c("Amy", "Bob"), each=6),
                 A=c(9, 7, 6, 8, 6, 9, 3, 2, 1, 5, 6, 5),
                 B=c(6, 7, 8, 5, 6, 7, 5, 4, 6, 3, 1, 5))

library(tidyr)

pivot_wider(
  jj,
  names_from = "student",
  values_from = c("A","B"),
  names_sep = ".",
  values_fn = list(A= list, B= list)) %>%
  unchop(everything())
#> # A tibble: 6 x 5
#>   month A.Amy A.Bob B.Amy B.Bob
#>   <int> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#> 1     1     9     3     6     5
#> 2     1     8     5     5     3
#> 3     2     7     2     7     4
#> 4     2     6     6     6     1
#> 5     3     6     1     8     6
#> 6     3     9     5     7     5
```

<sup>Created on 2019-09-14 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

The twist in this problem is that month is not unique by student, to solve this :

- `values_fn = list(A= list, B= list))` puts the multiple values in a list
- `unchop(everything())` unnest the lists vertically, you can use `unnest` as well here

Answer (score 1):

If we create a unique sequence, then we can the output in the correct format with `pivot_wider`

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
jj %>%
   group_by(month, student) %>% 
   mutate(rn = row_number()) %>%
   pivot_wider(names_from = 'student', values_from = c('A', 'B'), 
          names_sep='.')  %>% 
   select(-rn)
# A tibble: 6 x 5
# Groups:   month [3]
#  month A.Amy A.Bob B.Amy B.Bob
#  <int> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#1     1     9     3     6     5
#2     2     7     2     7     4
#3     3     6     1     8     6
#4     1     8     5     5     3
#5     2     6     6     6     1
#6     3     9     5     7     5
```

#### data

```
jj <- structure(list(month = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 
1L, 2L, 3L), student = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("Amy", "Bob"), class = "factor"), 
    A = c(9, 7, 6, 8, 6, 9, 3, 2, 1, 5, 6, 5), B = c(6, 7, 8, 
    5, 6, 7, 5, 4, 6, 3, 1, 5)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-12L))
```