# Create 'dummy variables' by spreading duplicate rows into columns in R

Tags: r, dplyr

thanks in advance for the help.

There are several questions using `spread` (from long to wide) on duplicate rows with `unite` such as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39053451/using-spread-with-duplicate-identifiers-for-rows).

I think what makes my question unique is the need to output dummy variables.

I anticipate an input like so:

```
df <- data.frame(id = c(1,1,2,3,4), fruit = c("apple","pear","apple","orange","apple"))
```

And an output like so:

```
output <- data.frame(id=c(1,2,3,4), apple = c(1,1,0,1), pear = c(1,0,0,0), orange = c(0,0,1,0))
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Using `tidyverse` you can add new column and than use `spread`.

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>% mutate(i = 1) %>% spread(fruit, i, fill = 0)

# result
  id apple orange pear
1  1     1      0    1
2  2     1      0    0
3  3     0      1    0
4  4     1      0    0
```

Comment: Thanks. Both this comment and @clemens are on point. I should have been more specific about my preference for dplyr. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 2):

You can use `dcast()` from the `data.table` package.

```
data.table::dcast(df, 
                  id ~ fruit, 
                  fun.aggregate = function(x) 1L,
                  fill = 0L)
```

Which will return

```
  id apple orange pear
1  1     1      0    1
2  2     1      0    0
3  3     0      1    0
4  4     1      0    0
```