# Compare content of multiple columns in 1 dataframe, and output booleans to a second dataframe

Tags: r

I am attempting to convert a data frame to a more easily readable format (by humans). The current data frame (DF1) contains a list of strings (questions) in Column A, and a list of strings (categories) in Column B. Where an item fits into multiple categories, there is another row further down in DF1 with the same question in Column A, but a different category in column B.

e.g.

```
   column1       column2      Column3
"question 1"   "category A"  "subcategory A"
"question 2"   "category A"  "subcategory B"
"question 1"   "category B"  "subcategory A"
```

I want to convert the data frame to have the question, and column B categories as column headers, with booleans indicating whether the question does or does not fall under that category.

e.g.

```
  Question    CategoryA    CategoryB
"question 1"    TRUE         TRUE
"question 2"    TRUE         FALSE
```

I have extracted a list of unique questions from DF1 using the following:

```
question <- list()
for (x in DF1$column1){
  if (!(x %in% question)){
    question[[x]] <- x
  }
}
```

What is the best way to do this in R? I'd prefer to avoid a series of nested loops if possible as I believe this can become very inefficient in R?

Many thanks!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does something like this do the trick

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

column1 <- c(
"question 1",   
"question 2" , 
"question 1" )

column2   <- c(
"category A"  ,
"category A"  ,
"category B"  )


column3 <- c(
"subcategory A",
"subcategory B",
"subcategory A")

df <- data.frame(column1, column2, column3, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

dfwide <- df %>% 
          select(-column3) %>% 
          mutate(col4 = TRUE) %>% 
          spread(column1, col4, fill= FALSE)
```

Comment: Not quite - returns the error message: Error: Duplicate identifiers for rows (151, 158, 159, 665, 1592, 1599, 1600, 2106, 3033, 3040, 3041, 3547), (1325, 2766, 4207), (1322, 2763, 4204)...... etc

Comment: From the data provided I did not get that error. here is a link that will show you how to resolve that issue, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39053451/using-spread-with-duplicate-identifiers-for-rows . If you can't get it to work you will need to share more data so I can produce the error and correct the answer