# how to create new variables from one variable using two rules

Tags: r, dataframe, tidyverse, tidyr, reshape2

I would appreciate any help to create new variables from one variable.

Specifically, I need help to simultaneously create one row per each `ID` and various columns of `E`, where each of the new columns of `E`, (that is, `E1`, `E2`, `E3`) contains the values of `E` for each row of `ID`. I tried doing this which `melt` followed by `spread` but I am getting the error:

> Error: Duplicate identifiers for rows (4, 7, 9), (1, 3, 6), (2, 5, 8)

Additionally, I tried the solutions discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39053451/using-spread-with-duplicate-identifiers-for-rows) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29775461/how-can-i-spread-repeated-measures-of-multiple-variables-into-wide-format) but these did not work for my case because I need to be able to create `row identifiers` for rows (4, 1, 2), (7, 3, 5), and (9, 6, 8). That is, `E` for rows (4, 1, 2) should be named `E1`, `E` for rows (7, 3, 5) should be named `E2`, `E` for rows (9, 6, 8) should be named `E3`, and so on.

**#data**

```
dT<-structure(list(A = c("a1", "a2", "a1", "a1", "a2", "a1", "a1", 
    "a2", "a1"), B = c("b2", "b2", "b2", "b1", "b2", "b2", "b1", 
    "b2", "b1"), ID = c("3", "4", "3", "1", "4", "3", "1", "4", "1"
    ), E = c(0.621142094943352, 0.742109450696123, 0.39439152996948, 
    0.40694392882818, 0.779607277916503, 0.550579323666347, 0.352622183880119, 
    0.690660491345867, 0.23378944873769)), class = c("data.table", 
    "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -9L))
```

**#my attempt**

```
    A  B ID         E
1: a1 b2  3 0.6211421
2: a2 b2  4 0.7421095
3: a1 b2  3 0.3943915
4: a1 b1  1 0.4069439
5: a2 b2  4 0.7796073
6: a1 b2  3 0.5505793
7: a1 b1  1 0.3526222
8: a2 b2  4 0.6906605
9: a1 b1  1 0.2337894

aTempDF <- melt(dT, id.vars = c("A", "B", "ID")) )

    A  B  ID variable    value
1: a1 b2  3        E 0.6211421
2: a2 b2  4        E 0.7421095
3: a1 b2  3        E 0.3943915
4: a1 b1  1        E 0.4069439
5: a2 b2  4        E 0.7796073
6: a1 b2  3        E 0.5505793
7: a1 b1  1        E 0.3526222
8: a2 b2  4        E 0.6906605
9: a1 b1  1        E 0.2337894

aTempDF%>%spread(variable, value)

Error: Duplicate identifiers for rows (4, 7, 9), (1, 3, 6), (2, 5, 8)
```

**#expected output**

```
    A  B  ID       E1           E2           E3
1: a1 b2  3        0.6211421    0.3943915    0.5505793
2: a2 b2  4        0.7421095    0.7796073    0.6906605 
3: a1 b1  1        0.4069439    0.3526222    0.2337894
```

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: The original question has already been answered. Please create a new question instead of invalidating existing answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `dcast` from `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
dcast(dT, A + B + ID ~ paste0("E", rowid(ID)))
#   A  B ID        E1        E2        E3
#1 a1 b1  1 0.4069439 0.3526222 0.2337894
#2 a1 b2  3 0.6211421 0.3943915 0.5505793
#3 a2 b2  4 0.7421095 0.7796073 0.6906605
```

You need to create the correct 'time variable' first which is what `rowid(ID)` does.

Comment: Hi @markus. Strangely, it seems that the solution works well for a small dataset (sample) but does not work for the actual dataset to which I want to use. I have edited and attached the bigger data. Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 1):

For those looking for a `tidyverse` solution:

```r
library(tidyverse)

dT <- structure(
  list(
    A = c("a1", "a2", "a1", "a1", "a2", "a1", "a1", "a2", "a1"),
    B = c("b2", "b2", "b2", "b1", "b2", "b2", "b1", "b2", "b1"),
    ID = c("3", "4", "3", "1", "4", "3", "1", "4", "1"),
    E = c(0.621142094943352, 0.742109450696123, 0.39439152996948, 0.40694392882818,
          0.550579323666347, 0.352622183880119, 0.690660491345867, 0.23378944873769,
          0.779607277916503)),
  class = c("data.table", 
            "data.frame"),
  row.names = c(NA, -9L))
```

```r
dT %>% 
  as_tibble() %>%  # since dataset is a data.table object
  group_by(A, B, ID) %>% 
  # Just so columns are "E1", "E2", etc.
  mutate(rn = glue::glue("E{row_number()}")) %>% 
  ungroup() %>% 
  spread(rn, E) %>%
  # not necessary, just making output in the same order as your expected output
  arrange(desc(B))
```

```
# A tibble: 3 x 6
#  A     B     ID       E1    E2    E3
#  <chr> <chr> <chr> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#1 a1    b2    3     0.621 0.394 0.551
#2 a2    b2    4     0.742 0.780 0.691
#3 a1    b1    1     0.407 0.353 0.234
```

As mentioned in the accepted answer, you need a "key" variable to spread on first. This is created using `row_number()` and `glue` where `glue` just gives you the proper E1, E2, etc. variable names.

The `group_by` piece just makes sure that the row numbers are with respect to A, B and ID.

**EDIT for tidyr >= 1.0.0**

The (not-so) new `pivot_` functions supercede `gather` and `spread` and eliminate the need to `glue` the new variable names together in a mutate.

```r
dT %>% 
  as_tibble() %>%  # since dataset is a data.table object
  group_by(A, B, ID) %>% 
  # no longer need to glue (or paste) the names together but still need a row number
  mutate(rn = row_number()) %>% 
  ungroup() %>% 
  pivot_wider(names_from = rn, values_from = E, names_glue = "E{.name}") %>% # names_glue argument allows for easy transforming of the new variable names
  # not necessary, just making output in the same order as your expected output
  arrange(desc(B))
```

```
# A tibble: 3 x 6
#  A     B     ID       E1    E2    E3
#  <chr> <chr> <chr> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#1 a1    b2    3     0.621 0.394 0.551
#2 a2    b2    4     0.742 0.780 0.691
#3 a1    b1    1     0.407 0.353 0.234
```