# how to create new variables from one variable

Tags: r, data.table, reshape, tidyverse, tidyr

> I would appreciate any help to create new variables from one variable
>   in my actual dataset, which can be downloaded [here](https://jmp.sh/brt1dDw).

Given this sample data:

```
dT<-structure(list(A = c("a1", "a2", "a1", "a1", "a2", "a1", "a1", 
    "a2", "a1"), B = c("b2", "b2", "b2", "b1", "b2", "b2", "b1", 
    "b2", "b1"), ID = c("3", "4", "3", "1", "4", "3", "1", "4", "1"
    ), E = c(0.621142094943352, 0.742109450696123, 0.39439152996948, 
    0.40694392882818, 0.779607277916503, 0.550579323666347, 0.352622183880119, 
    0.690660491345867, 0.23378944873769)), class = c("data.table", 
    "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -9L))
```

this code works to create several variables from the variable `E` as [expected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54470212/how-to-create-new-variables-from-one-variable-using-two-rules?noredirect=1#comment95751447_54470212):

```
library(data.table)
dcast(dT, A + B + ID ~ paste0("E", rowid(ID)))
#   A  B ID        E1        E2        E3
#1 a1 b1  1 0.4069439 0.3526222 0.2337894
#2 a1 b2  3 0.6211421 0.3943915 0.5505793
#3 a2 b2  4 0.7421095 0.7796073 0.6906605
```

> However, when I apply the same code to a larger dataset - available
>   [here](https://jmp.sh/brt1dDw), which is the actual data to which I want to apply the
>   operation, `data.table` does not give the expected output as
>   illustrated below (and available [here](https://jmp.sh/phVBOSW)) - this is the incorrect output:

```
library(readr)
mydata <- read_csv("mydata.csv")  
library(data.table)
myDT<-dcast(mydata, A + B + ID ~ paste0("E", rowid(ID)))
View(myDT)
```

[image]

**What I want is to be able to get this output ([the incorrect output](https://jmp.sh/9dWVoCE)) from the larger dataset structured like the output that I get when I use a smaller dataset ([the correct output](https://jmp.sh/rxf0aeU)).**

I tried the solutions discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39053451/using-spread-with-duplicate-identifiers-for-rows) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29775461/how-can-i-spread-repeated-measures-of-multiple-variables-into-wide-format) but these did not work for my case as discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54470212/how-to-create-new-variables-from-one-variable-using-two-rules?noredirect=1#comment95751447_54470212).

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/187723/discussion-on-question-by-krantz-how-to-create-new-variables-from-one-variable).

Comment: Hi all, I just posted a related question at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54488761/how-to-create-categories-conditionally-using-other-variables-values-and-sequence. Thanks in advance for any help.