# how to create categories conditionally using other variables values and sequence

Tags: r, function, data.table, reshape, tidyr

I would appreciate any help to create a function that allows me to create categories of one variable using the order of a set of other variables values.

> Specifically, I want a function that:
>
> 1. creates category `E1` of the variable `variable` the `first` time that each combination of values of the variables `A`, `B`, and `ID`
>      appears in the dataset.
> 2. creates category `E2` of the variable `variable` the `second` time that each combination of values of the variables `A`, `B`, and `ID`
>      appears in the dataset.
> 3. creates category `E3` of the variable `variable` the `third` time that each combination of values of the variables `A`, `B`, and `ID`
>      appears in the dataset.
> 4. creates category `En` of the variable `variable` the `nth` time that each combination of values of the variables `A`, `B`, and `ID`
>      appears in the dataset.

**#sample data:**

```
rowdT<-structure(list(A = c("a1", "a2", "a1", "a1", "a2", "a1", "a1", 
            "a2", "a1"), B = c("b2", "b2", "b2", "b1", "b2", "b2", "b1", 
            "b2", "b1"), ID = c("3", "4", "3", "1", "4", "3", "1", "4", "1"
            ), E = c(0.621142094943352, 0.742109450696123, 0.39439152996948, 
            0.40694392882818, 0.779607277916503, 0.550579323666347, 0.352622183880119, 
            0.690660491345867, 0.23378944873769)), class = c("data.table", 
            "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -9L))     
sampleDT <- melt(rowdT, id.vars = c("A", "B", "ID"))
```

**#input data:**

```
    A  B  ID variable    value
1: a1 b2  3        E 0.6211421
2: a2 b2  4        E 0.7421095
3: a1 b2  3        E 0.3943915
4: a1 b1  1        E 0.4069439
5: a2 b2  4        E 0.7796073
6: a1 b2  3        E 0.5505793
7: a1 b1  1        E 0.3526222
8: a2 b2  4        E 0.6906605
9: a1 b1  1        E 0.2337894
```

**#expected output:**

```
    A  B  ID variable    value
4: a1 b1  1        E1 0.4069439
1: a1 b2  3        E1 0.6211421
2: a2 b2  4        E1 0.7421095
7: a1 b1  1        E2 0.3526222
3: a1 b2  3        E2 0.3943915
5: a2 b2  4        E2 0.7796073
9: a1 b1  1        E3 0.2337894
6: a1 b2  3        E3 0.5505793
8: a2 b2  4        E3 0.6906605
```

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: `sampleDT%>%group_by(A,B,ID)%>%mutate(variable=paste0('E',1:n())`

Comment: And when I add `)` it gives the error: `Error: This function should not be called directly`

Comment: It works for me. `library(dplyr);library(data.table);sampleDT%>%group_by(A,B,ID)%>%mutate(variable=paste0('E',1:n()))`

Comment: It works after I do `detach("package:plyr", unload = TRUE)`. Thanks, @A.Suliman.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First convert your variable to a character vector for proper coercion, and then use `data.table`

```
sampleDT$variable = as.character(sampleDT$variable)

sampleDT[, variable := paste(variable,1:.N,sep = ""), by = c("A", "B", "ID")]
```

This creates unique tallies based on the observed combinations of `A`, `B`, and `ID`.

This gets the following output:

```
    A  B ID variable     value
1: a1 b2  3       E1 0.6211421
2: a2 b2  4       E1 0.7421095
3: a1 b2  3       E2 0.3943915
4: a1 b1  1       E1 0.4069439
5: a2 b2  4       E2 0.7796073
6: a1 b2  3       E3 0.5505793
7: a1 b1  1       E2 0.3526222
8: a2 b2  4       E3 0.6906605
9: a1 b1  1       E3 0.2337894
```

which you can reorder if necessary.

Comment: Still testing the solution with the large dataset. I will let you know if it works. Thanks for this.

Comment: Another variant of this answer: `sampleDT[, v := paste0(variable, rowid(A, B, ID))]`

Comment: Thanks for the help, @sumshyftw. Your solution works with my larger data as well. Just finished the test.

Comment: Thanks for the help, @Frank. Your solution works with my larger data as well. Just finished the test.