# wide to long and back to wide again

Tags: r, tidyr

I am having a Little difficulty with getting my data back to the "original" format.

The data is the following:

```
       stocks      bills      bonds         gold
1   0.4496607  0.0423607  0.0199607  0.011560700
2  -0.0888480  0.0257520  0.0361520 -0.005848000
3  -0.1872465  0.1094535  0.1093535  0.063953500
4  -0.3452323  0.1162677  0.0675677  0.093167700
5   0.0163397  0.1134397  0.1906397  0.102739700
6   0.4921664  0.0019664  0.0109664  0.439369260
7  -0.0270515 -0.0119515  0.0644485  0.064510328
8   0.4375493 -0.0280507  0.0148493 -0.029850700
9   0.3049072 -0.0127928  0.0357072 -0.014492800
10 -0.3819714 -0.0255714 -0.0147714 -0.028571400
11  0.3205778  0.0285778  0.0698778  0.027777800
12 -0.0110000  0.0004000  0.0441000  0.000000000
13 -0.1138429 -0.0068429  0.0468571 -0.021531637
14 -0.2269908 -0.0984908 -0.1194908 -0.070717428
15  0.1013774 -0.0869226 -0.0674226 -0.090322600
16  0.2210142 -0.0257858 -0.0046858 -0.001806236
17  0.1673115 -0.0191885  0.0028115 -0.029861379
18  0.3357281 -0.0186719  0.0155281  0.004740664
19 -0.2656187 -0.1775187 -0.1500187 -0.154827085
20 -0.0363721 -0.0826721 -0.0791721  0.028684455
```

Code:

```
d <- df %>%
  gather(assets, rets, stocks:gold, factor_key=TRUE)

d %>%
  spread(assets, rets)
```

> Error: Duplicate identifiers for rows (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10,
>   11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20), (21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27,
>   28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40), (41, 42, 43, 44,
>   45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 58, 59, 60), (61,
>   62, 63, 64, 65, 66, 67, 68, 69, 70, 71, 72, 73, 74, 75, 76, 77, 78,
>   79, 80)

How can I put the data back into the same format as I originally had it?

Data

```
structure(list(stocks = c(0.4496607, -0.088848, -0.1872465, -0.3452323, 
0.0163397, 0.4921664, -0.0270515, 0.4375493, 0.3049072, -0.3819714, 
0.3205778, -0.011, -0.1138429, -0.2269908, 0.1013774, 0.2210142, 
0.1673115, 0.3357281, -0.2656187, -0.0363721), bills = c(0.0423607, 
0.025752, 0.1094535, 0.1162677, 0.1134397, 0.0019664, -0.0119515, 
-0.0280507, -0.0127928, -0.0255714, 0.0285778, 0.0004, -0.0068429, 
-0.0984908, -0.0869226, -0.0257858, -0.0191885, -0.0186719, -0.1775187, 
-0.0826721), bonds = c(0.0199607, 0.036152, 0.1093535, 0.0675677, 
0.1906397, 0.0109664, 0.0644485, 0.0148493, 0.0357072, -0.0147714, 
0.0698778, 0.0441, 0.0468571, -0.1194908, -0.0674226, -0.0046858, 
0.0028115, 0.0155281, -0.1500187, -0.0791721), gold = c(0.0115607, 
-0.005848, 0.0639535, 0.0931677, 0.1027397, 0.43936926, 0.064510328, 
-0.0298507, -0.0144928, -0.0285714, 0.0277778, 0, -0.021531637, 
-0.070717428, -0.0903226, -0.001806236, -0.029861379, 0.004740664, 
-0.154827085, 0.028684455)), row.names = c(NA, 20L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Thanks I am taking a look at it: Applying `d2 <- d %>%
  dcast(rets ~ assets)` gets some weird results.

Comment: This answer is probably what you want: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44511254/5150629 Before `spread`ing your dataset, you need to create an id variable.

Comment: Agree with needing to add an id variable. Think about how your code is working. How does `spread()` know which values go in which rows? When you `gather()` you don't have any indicator left to tell the software how to line things back up.