# R - dplyr split merge map

Tags: r, dplyr

I would like to find an efficient way to split and merge back my data. 
I want to split my data by `sex` and merged it back by household id (`idhouse`). I am doing this to get a `paired` database (so, I want to remove all the "singles").

What I have is this

```
   idhouse idperso   sex score
1       1       1   man    18
2       1       2 woman    22
3       2       1   man    19
4       2       2 woman    24
5       3       1 woman    30
```

want I want is this :

```
 idhouse idperso_man score_man idperso_woman score_woman
     1           1        18             2          22
     2           1        19             2          24
```

I am having a mistake using `map` and I can't figure what it is

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr) 

dt %>% split(.$sex) %>% 
   map_df(~merge(., .$man, .$woman, by = 'idhouse'))
```

#### data

```
dt = structure(list(idhouse = structure(c(1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L), .Label = c("1", 
"2", "3"), class = "factor"), idperso = structure(c(1L, 2L, 1L, 
2L, 1L), .Label = c("1", "2"), class = "factor"), sex = structure(c(1L, 
2L, 1L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("man", "woman"), class = "factor"), 
score = structure(c(1L, 3L, 2L, 4L, 5L), .Label = c("18", 
"19", "22", "24", "30"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("idhouse", 
"idperso", "sex", "score"), row.names = c(NA, -5L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Hey @giacomoV, see this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30592094/r-spreading-multiple-columns-with-tidyr.  This is a dupe which should be closed

Comment: @DavidArenburg, haha I justed posted an answer of yours as the dupe.

Comment: @JacobH yeah, totally forgot about that one :)

Comment: Im not sure about the duplicate because it's not really about spreading but rather on merging in order to clean and pair a dataset. I have to merge one way or the other. No?

Comment: @giacomoV the code in the link I provided above generates your desired output, so I believe it is a dupe.  However I could be wrong, why do you want to merge?

Comment: Because people from the same household must be matched and when there is a singleton (like `id == 3` in my example) then he must be delete. I don't understand how the code proposed solve this. Thanks

Comment: @giacomoV, yes you're right you can use merge, to merge on `idhouse`, however, it is not necessary.  When you reshape the data from long to wide format, `idhouse` will be matched.  As for your second point, the post which I've provided you will not remove the singletons.  However, removing the singletons is trivial.  For example, if you're using the `tidyr` approach in the post you simply need to include `%>%   slice(complete.cases(.))` at the end of the chain.

Comment: If you want to see  how this is a dupe, here is the `data.table` solution from the mentioned dupes + `complete.cases` at the end `library(data.table) ; res <- dcast(setDT(dt), idhouse ~ sex, value.var = c("idperso", "score")) ; res[complete.cases(res)]`. You can do the same with dplyr/tidyr or reshape2 and add `complete.cases` at the end

Comment: ok thank you very much.