# modelr: Fitting multiple models with resampled data

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyr, purrr

In the [tidy model of data science (TM)](http://r4ds.had.co.nz/) implemented in [`modelr`](https://github.com/hadley/modelr), resampled data are organized using [list-columns](http://r4ds.had.co.nz/many-models.html#list-columns-1):

```
library(modelr)
library(tidyverse)

# create the k-folds
df_heights_resampled = heights %>% 
  crossv_kfold(k = 10, id = "Resample ID")
```

It is possible to `map` a model to each of the training datasets in the list-column `train` and to compute a performance metric by `map`ping onto the list-column `test`.

In case this needs to be done withe multiple models, this needs to be repeated for each of the models.

```
# create a list of formulas 
formulas_heights = formulas(
  .response = ~ income, 
  model1  = ~ height + weight + marital + sex,
  model2 = ~ height + weight + marital + sex + education
) 

# fit each of the models in the list of formulas
df_heights_resampled = df_heights_resampled %>% 
  mutate(
    model1 = map(train, function(train_data) {
      lm(formulas_heights[[1]], data = train_data)
    }),
    model2 = map(train, function(train_data) {
      lm(formulas_heights[[2]], data = train_data)
    })
  )

# score the models on the test sets
df_heights_resampled = df_heights_resampled %>% 
  mutate(
    rmse1 = map2_dbl(.x = model1, .y = test, .f = rmse),
    rmse2 = map2_dbl(.x = model2, .y = test, .f = rmse)
  )
```

which gives:

```
> df_heights_resampled
# A tibble: 10 × 7
            train           test `Resample ID`   model1   model2    rmse1    rmse2
           <list>         <list>         <chr>   <list>   <list>    <dbl>    <dbl>
1  <S3: resample> <S3: resample>            01 <S3: lm> <S3: lm> 58018.35 53903.99
2  <S3: resample> <S3: resample>            02 <S3: lm> <S3: lm> 55117.37 50279.38
3  <S3: resample> <S3: resample>            03 <S3: lm> <S3: lm> 49005.82 44613.93
4  <S3: resample> <S3: resample>            04 <S3: lm> <S3: lm> 55437.07 51068.90
5  <S3: resample> <S3: resample>            05 <S3: lm> <S3: lm> 48845.35 44673.88
6  <S3: resample> <S3: resample>            06 <S3: lm> <S3: lm> 58226.69 54010.50
7  <S3: resample> <S3: resample>            07 <S3: lm> <S3: lm> 56571.93 53322.41
8  <S3: resample> <S3: resample>            08 <S3: lm> <S3: lm> 46084.82 42294.50
9  <S3: resample> <S3: resample>            09 <S3: lm> <S3: lm> 59762.22 54814.55
10 <S3: resample> <S3: resample>            10 <S3: lm> <S3: lm> 45328.48 41882.79
```

## Question:

This can get cumbersome really fast if the number of models to be explored is large. `modelr` provides the `fit_with` function that allows to iterate over a number of models (as characterized by multiple formulae) but that does not seem to allow for a list-column like `train` in the model above. I am assuming that one of the `*map*` family of functions will make this possible (`invoke_map`?), but have not been able to figure out how.

Answer (score 3):

You can programmatically build the calls using `map` and `lazyeval::interp`. I'm curious if there is a pure `purrr` solution, but the issue is that you want to create multiple columns, and you need multiple calls for that. Perhaps a `purrr` solution would create another list column containing all models.

```
library(lazyeval)
model_calls <- map(formulas_heights, 
                   ~interp(~map(train, ~lm(form, data = .x)), form = .x))
score_calls <- map(names(model_calls), 
                   ~interp(~map2_dbl(.x = m, .y = test, .f = rmse), m = as.name(.x)))
names(score_calls) <- paste0("rmse", seq_along(score_calls))

df_heights_resampled %>% mutate_(.dots = c(model_calls, score_calls))
```

> ```
> # A tibble: 10 × 7
>             train           test `Resample ID`   model1   model2    rmse1    rmse2
>            <list>         <list>         <chr>   <list>   <list>    <dbl>    <dbl>
> 1  <S3: resample> <S3: resample>            01 <S3: lm> <S3: lm> 44720.86 41452.07
> 2  <S3: resample> <S3: resample>            02 <S3: lm> <S3: lm> 54174.38 48823.03
> 3  <S3: resample> <S3: resample>            03 <S3: lm> <S3: lm> 56854.21 52725.62
> 4  <S3: resample> <S3: resample>            04 <S3: lm> <S3: lm> 53312.38 48797.48
> 5  <S3: resample> <S3: resample>            05 <S3: lm> <S3: lm> 61883.90 57469.17
> 6  <S3: resample> <S3: resample>            06 <S3: lm> <S3: lm> 55709.83 50867.26
> 7  <S3: resample> <S3: resample>            07 <S3: lm> <S3: lm> 53036.06 48698.07
> 8  <S3: resample> <S3: resample>            08 <S3: lm> <S3: lm> 55986.83 52717.94
> 9  <S3: resample> <S3: resample>            09 <S3: lm> <S3: lm> 51738.60 48006.74
> 10 <S3: resample> <S3: resample>            10 <S3: lm> <S3: lm> 45061.22 41480.35
> ```

Comment: I like this solution, but I think that there is a more straightforward solution that I have [posted about on the `modelr` issues page](https://github.com/hadley/modelr/issues/31#issuecomment-255596156). The remaining issue is to split that list-column out into its constituents, for which I am sure there is (should be) a solution in `purrr`.

Comment: Well you can always post an answer to your own question, but a list of lists within a data.frame may be a little much for some.

Comment: Not a complete solution until I can figure out how to split it out from the list-column. Whence it is just columns of S3 objects like all the rest of them. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Inspired by [my own question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41404198/fit-a-different-model-for-each-row-of-a-list-columns-data-frame), I think there is a similar approach to this question.

First, define a function that can take arguments of data and formula in list-column structure and estimate a model with the inputs:

```
est_model <- function(data, formula, ...) {
  map(list(data), formula, ...)[[1]]
}
```

It'd be then straightforward to estimate multiple models with each CV fold and formula pair:

```
library(gapminder)
library(tidyverse)
library(modelr)

cv_gm <- gapminder %>% 
  crossv_kfold(k = 10, id = "Resample ID")

# Assume 4 different formulae
formulae_tbl <- tibble::frame_data(
  ~model, ~fmla,
  1, ~lm(lifeExp ~ year, data = .),
  2, ~lm(lifeExp ~ year + pop, data = .),
  3, ~lm(lifeExp ~ year + gdpPercap, data = .),
  4, ~lm(lifeExp ~ year + pop + gdpPercap, data = .)
)

cv_gm_results <- cv_gm %>% 
  tidyr::crossing(formulae_tbl)

cv_gm_results <- cv_gm_results %>% 
  mutate(fit=map2(train, fmla, est_model),
         rmse=map2_dbl(fit, test, .f = rmse))
```

Arguably, according to the tidy data philosophy, it is better to work with `cv_gm_results` onward, but if you want it in the shape in the original question (h/t [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30592094/r-spreading-multiple-columns-with-tidyr)):

```
cv_gm_results %>% 
  select(`Resample ID`, model, fit, rmse) %>% 
  gather(variable, value, fit, rmse) %>%
  unite(temp, variable, model, sep="") %>%
  spread(temp, value) %>% 
  mutate_at(.cols=vars(starts_with("rmse")), .funs=flatten_dbl)

# A tibble: 10 × 9
   `Resample ID`     fit1     fit2     fit3     fit4    rmse1    rmse2
           <chr>   <list>   <list>   <list>   <list>    <dbl>    <dbl>
1             01 <S3: lm> <S3: lm> <S3: lm> <S3: lm> 11.32344 11.32201
2             02 <S3: lm> <S3: lm> <S3: lm> <S3: lm> 11.34626 11.33175
3             03 <S3: lm> <S3: lm> <S3: lm> <S3: lm> 11.62480 11.60221
4             04 <S3: lm> <S3: lm> <S3: lm> <S3: lm> 10.80946 10.81421
5             05 <S3: lm> <S3: lm> <S3: lm> <S3: lm> 11.52413 11.52384
6             06 <S3: lm> <S3: lm> <S3: lm> <S3: lm> 12.10914 12.08134
7             07 <S3: lm> <S3: lm> <S3: lm> <S3: lm> 11.97641 12.00809
8             08 <S3: lm> <S3: lm> <S3: lm> <S3: lm> 12.30191 12.31489
9             09 <S3: lm> <S3: lm> <S3: lm> <S3: lm> 11.96970 11.95617
10            10 <S3: lm> <S3: lm> <S3: lm> <S3: lm> 11.30289 11.30294
# ... with 2 more variables: rmse3 <dbl>, rmse4 <dbl>
```

**Update**

It turns out est_model() is not necessary, `purrr` provides [`at_depth()`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/purrr/purrr.pdf) that works for our purpose:

```
cv_gm_results <- cv_gm_results %>% 
  mutate(fit=map2(train, fmla, ~at_depth(.x, 0, .y)),
         rmse=map2_dbl(fit, test, .f = rmse))
```