# Moving rows to columns in R using identifier

Tags: r

I have a dataset in r with two columns of numerical data and one with an identifier. Some of the rows share the same identifier (i.e. they are the same individual), but contain different data. I want to use the identifier to move those that share an identifier from a row into a columns. There are currently 600 rows, but there should be 400.

Can anyone share r code that might do this? I am new to R, and have tried the reshape (cast) programme, but I can't really follow it, and am not sure it's exactly what i'm trying to do.

Any help gratefully appreciated.

UPDATE:

Current

```
ID Age Sex  
1   3   1  
1   5   1  
1   6   1  
1   7   1  
2   1   2  
2   12  2  
2   5   2  
3   3   1
```

Expected output

```
ID Age Sex Age2 Sex2 Age3 Sex3 Age4 Sex4   
1   3   1   5    1     6    1    7    1
2   1   2   12   2     5    2
3   3   1
```

UPDATE 2:

So far I have tried using the melt and dcast commands from reshape2. I am getting there, but it still doesn't look quite right. Here is my code:

```
x <- melt(example, id.vars = "ID")

x$time <- ave(x$ID, x$ID, FUN = seq_along)

example2 <- dcast (x, ID ~ time, value.var = "value")
```

and here is the output using that code:

```
ID  A   B   C    D     E    F    G    H (for clarity i have labelled these) 
1   3   5   6    7     1    1    1    1
2   1   12  5    2     2    2
3   3   1
```

So, as you can probably see, it is mixing up the 'sex' and 'age' variables and combining them in the same column. For example column D has the value '7' for person 1 (age4), but '2' for person 2 (Sex). I can see that my code is not instructing where the numerical values should be cast to, but I do not know how to code that part. Any ideas?

Comment: Please show a small reproducible example and expected output based on that

Comment: Please `edit` your post and update it

Comment: it would be helpful to show what you have tried, what went wrong with that attempt, what else you have tried. SO is not a place for others to just write code for you

Answer (score 1):

Here's an approach using `gather`, `spread` and `unite` from the `tidyr` package:

```r
suppressPackageStartupMessages(library(tidyverse))  
x <- tribble(
  ~ID, ~Age, ~Sex,  
  1,   3,   1,  
  1,   5,   1,  
  1,   6,   1,  
  1,   7,   1,  
  2,   1,   2,  
  2,   12,  2,  
  2,   5,   2,  
  3,   3,   1  
)

x %>% group_by(ID) %>%
  mutate(grp = 1:n()) %>%
  gather(var, val, -ID, -grp) %>%
  unite("var_grp", var, grp, sep ='') %>%
  spread(var_grp, val, fill = '')
#> # A tibble: 3 x 9
#> # Groups:   ID [3]
#>      ID  Age1  Age2  Age3  Age4  Sex1  Sex2  Sex3  Sex4
#> * <dbl> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr>
#> 1     1     3     5     6     7     1     1     1     1
#> 2     2     1    12     5           2     2     2      
#> 3     3     3                       1
```

If you prefer to keep the columns numeric then just remove the `fill=''` argument from `spread(var_grp, val, fill = '')`.

Other questions which might help with this include:

[R spreading multiple columns with tidyr](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30592094/r-spreading-multiple-columns-with-tidyr)

[How can I spread repeated measures of multiple variables into wide format?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29775461/how-can-i-spread-repeated-measures-of-multiple-variables-into-wide-format)

Comment: Many thanks for your help - this worked for this particular problem. I'll now try and apply it to my real dataset.

Answer (score 0):

I have recently come across a similar issue in my data, and wanted to provide an update using the `tidyr` 1.0 functions as `gather` and `spread` have been retired. The new `pivot_longer` and `pivot_wider` are currently much slower than `gather` and `spread`, especially on very large datasets, but this is supposedly fixed in the next update of `tidyr`, so hope this updated solution is useful to people.

```r
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)

x %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
  mutate(grp = 1:n()) %>%
  pivot_longer(-c(ID, grp), names_to = "var", values_to = "val") %>%
  unite("var_grp", var, grp, sep = "") %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = var_grp, values_from = val)

#> # A tibble: 3 x 9
#> # Groups:   ID [3]
#>      ID  Age1  Sex1  Age2  Sex2  Age3  Sex3  Age4  Sex4
#>   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#> 1     1     3     1     5     1     6     1     7     1
#> 2     2     1     2    12     2     5     2    NA    NA
#> 3     3     3     1    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA
```