# Transpose rows to columns with multiple categories dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyr, spread

I would like to use `tidyr`'s spread function to convert a data frame with multiple id's in the rows and several columns into a df with one row where we have indicator columns for all the combinations of id's and categories.  If `dplyr` and `tidyr` is not the most appropriate for this, open to other spread-like functions.

In the script below, I'm able to only specify 1 column as the value pair.  I would like to have cat1 and cat2 as value columns.  Also, I would like the field names to be "sentid1_cat1, sentid1_cat2" etc.

```
test.df <- data.frame(sentid = 1:3, 
                      cat1 = c(1,0,0), 
                      cat2 = c(0,1,0))

test.df %>%
    spread(key = sentid, value = cat1, sep = '_')
```

**EDIT**

Desired output:

```
output.df <- data.frame(sentid1_cat1 = 1,
                        sentid1_cat2 = 0,
                        sentid2_cat1 = 0,
                        sentid2_cat2 = 1,
                        sentid3_cat1 = 0,
                        sentid3_cat2 = 0)
```

Comment: I am a little uncertain what you are asking.  Do you mind including an output df of what the desired result would look like?

Comment: Maybe [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30592094/r-spreading-multiple-columns-with-tidyr) will be helpful. It would be helpful if you show your desired output.

Comment: Does my answer solve your problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A solution with `dplyr` + `tidyr`:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

test.df %>%
  gather(variable, value, -sentid) %>%
  unite(variable, sentid, variable) %>%
  mutate(variable = paste0("sentid", variable)) %>%
  spread(variable, value)
```

**Result:**

```
  sentid1_cat1 sentid1_cat2 sentid2_cat1 sentid2_cat2 sentid3_cat1 sentid3_cat2
1            1            0            0            1            0            0
```