# Splitting based on multiple columns and then applying spread() in R

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyr, purrr

I am trying to split my data into 3 parts based on 3 columns, and then want to spread the data for further processing. However, when I split using 2 columns, the code works. It doesn't work for 3 columns. This is built upon the discussion at [How can I spread repeated measures of multiple variables into wide format?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29775461/tidyr-repeated-measures-multiple-variables-wide-format)

Here's my data:

```
structure(list(Zone = c("East", "East", "East", "East", "East", 
"East", "East", "West", "West", "West", "West", "West", "West", 
"West"), Fiscal.Year = c(2016, 2016, 2016, 2016, 2016, 2016, 
2017, 2016, 2016, 2016, 2017, 2017, 2018, 2018), Transaction.ID = c(132, 
133, 134, 135, 136, 137, 171, 171, 172, 173, 175, 176, 177, 178
), L.Rev = c(3, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 2, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 2, 1), L.Qty = c(3, 
0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 2, 1), A.Rev = c(0, 0, 0, 1, 
1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0), A.Qty = c(0, 0, 0, 2, 2, 3, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0), I.Rev = c(4, 4, 4, 0, 1, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 
1, 0, 1, 1), I.Qty = c(2, 2, 2, 0, 1, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 
1)), .Names = c("Zone", "Fiscal.Year", "Transaction.ID", "L.Rev", 
"L.Qty", "A.Rev", "A.Qty", "I.Rev", "I.Qty"), row.names = c(NA, 
14L), class = "data.frame")
```

Here's the code that works:

```
Input_File %>%
gather(Rev_Qty,Value, L.Rev:I.Qty)  %>%
separate(Rev_Qty, into=c("L.A","Rev.Qty")) %>% 
split(.,list(.$Zone,.$Rev.Qty)) %>%  
#Ideally, I want three-way split--i.e. Fiscal.Year, Zone and Rev.Qty
purrr::map(~unite(.,LAType.Rev.Qty, L.A, Rev.Qty, sep = ".")) %>% 
purrr::map(~spread_(.,key_col = "LAType.Rev.Qty", value_col = "Value"))
```

This works nicely--i.e. I get a list of length 4 that I can use for further processing.

However, the following code doesn't work when I apply three-way split based on `Rev.Qty`; `Zone` and `Fiscal.Year`.

```
Input_File %>%
gather(Rev_Qty,Value, L.Rev:I.Qty)  %>%
separate(Rev_Qty, into=c("L.A","Rev.Qty")) %>% 
#Now split the data based on zone, Rev vs. Qty and year--DOESN'T WORK
split(.,list(.$Zone,.$Rev.Qty,.$Fiscal.Year)) %>%
purrr::map(~unite(.,LAType.Rev.Qty, L.A, Rev.Qty, sep = ".")) %>% 
purrr::map(~spread_(.,key_col = "LAType.Rev.Qty", value_col = "Value"))
```

I get the following error:

```
Error in enc2utf8(col_names(col_labels, sep = sep)) : 
  argumemt is not a character vector
```

Upon debugging, I found that the code executes well until the `unite().` It breaks as soon as I call `spread_()`.

**Expected Output:** If we run the code until `unite()`, we will see that we will get a list of length 12. Expected output would be this list after the application of spread on `LAType.Rev.Qty` and `Value` columns. I hope this clarifies the expected output.

Can someone please help me what's going on? I am a beginner, and I've no clue what's happening.

Comment: @akrun - Thanks for your question. The expected output would be lists after data being spread. I am adding clarification now.

Comment: FWIW this is a bug in tidyr: https://github.com/tidyverse/tidyr/issues/269

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We need `drop=TRUE` in `split` to remove the combinations that do not exist in the dataset

```
Input_File %>%
      gather(Rev_Qty,Value, L.Rev:I.Qty)  %>%
      separate(Rev_Qty, into=c("L.A","Rev.Qty")) %>% 
      split(.,list(.$Zone,.$Rev.Qty,.$Fiscal.Year), drop = TRUE) %>%
      purrr::map(~unite(.,LAType.Rev.Qty, L.A, Rev.Qty, sep = ".")) %>% 
      purrr::map(~spread_(.,key_col = "LAType.Rev.Qty", value_col = "Value"))
```

Comment: Fantastic! do you mind explaining how you debugged this issue? I'm amazed! I spent about two hours, and was clueless...I'd appreciate your thought process. I am a beginner, so it will help me learn R.

Comment: @watchtower I was running the code step-by-step, and found that `split` gives some `list` elements with 0 rows, then I remembered the `drop=TRUE`

Comment: Sorry for requiring clarification- when you say "I found that `split` gives some `list` elements with 0 rows. Do you mind explaining what this means? I re-ran the code without `drop=TRUE`, but couldn't see "0 rows". I'd appreciate your thoughts.

Comment: @watchtower  If I ran up to the `split` step in your code, `$East.Rev.2018
[1] Zone           Fiscal.Year    Transaction.ID L.A            Rev.Qty        Value         
<0 rows> (or 0-length row.names)` i get this type of elements