# Spread multiple columns in a function

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyr, rlang

Often I need to `spread` multiple value columns, as in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29775461/324364) question. But I do it often enough that I'd like to be able to write a function that does this.

For example, given the data:

```
set.seed(42)
dat <- data_frame(id = rep(1:2,each = 2),
                  grp = rep(letters[1:2],times = 2),
                  avg = rnorm(4),
                  sd = runif(4))
> dat
# A tibble: 4 x 4
     id   grp        avg        sd
  <int> <chr>      <dbl>     <dbl>
1     1     a  1.3709584 0.6569923
2     1     b -0.5646982 0.7050648
3     2     a  0.3631284 0.4577418
4     2     b  0.6328626 0.7191123
```

I'd like to create a function that returns something like:

```
# A tibble: 2 x 5
     id     a_avg      b_avg      a_sd      b_sd
  <int>     <dbl>      <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>
1     1 1.3709584 -0.5646982 0.6569923 0.7050648
2     2 0.3631284  0.6328626 0.4577418 0.7191123
```

How can I do that?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

We'll return to the answer provided in the question linked to, but for the moment let's start with a more naive approach.

One idea would be to `spread` each value column individually, and then join the results, i.e.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(tibble)

dat_avg <- dat %>% 
    select(-sd) %>%
    spread(key = grp,value = avg) %>%
    rename(a_avg = a,
           b_avg = b)

dat_sd <- dat %>% 
    select(-avg) %>%
    spread(key = grp,value = sd) %>%
    rename(a_sd = a,
           b_sd = b)

> full_join(dat_avg,
          dat_sd,
          by = 'id')

# A tibble: 2 x 5
     id     a_avg      b_avg      a_sd      b_sd
  <int>     <dbl>      <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>
1     1 1.3709584 -0.5646982 0.6569923 0.7050648
2     2 0.3631284  0.6328626 0.4577418 0.7191123
```

(I used a `full_join` just in case we run into situations where not all combinations of the join columns appear in all of them.)

Let's start with a function that works like `spread` but allows you to pass the `key` and `value` columns as characters:

```
spread_chr <- function(data, key_col, value_cols, fill = NA, 
                       convert = FALSE,drop = TRUE,sep = NULL){
    n_val <- length(value_cols)
    result <- vector(mode = "list", length = n_val)
    id_cols <- setdiff(names(data), c(key_col,value_cols))

    for (i in seq_along(result)){
        result[[i]] <- spread(data = data[,c(id_cols,key_col,value_cols[i]),drop = FALSE],
                              key = !!key_col,
                              value = !!value_cols[i],
                              fill = fill,
                              convert = convert,
                              drop = drop,
                              sep = paste0(sep,value_cols[i],sep))
    }

    result %>%
        purrr::reduce(.f = full_join, by = id_cols)
}

> dat %>%
  spread_chr(key_col = "grp",
             value_cols = c("avg","sd"),
             sep = "_")

# A tibble: 2 x 5
     id grp_avg_a  grp_avg_b  grp_sd_a  grp_sd_b
  <int>     <dbl>      <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>
1     1 1.3709584 -0.5646982 0.6569923 0.7050648
2     2 0.3631284  0.6328626 0.4577418 0.7191123
```

The key ideas here are to unquote the arguments `key_col` and `value_cols[i]` using the `!!` operator, and using the `sep` argument in `spread` to control the resulting value column names.

If we wanted to convert this function to accept unquoted arguments for the key and value columns, we could modify it like so:

```
spread_nq <- function(data, key_col,..., fill = NA, 
                      convert = FALSE, drop = TRUE, sep = NULL){
    val_quos <- rlang::quos(...)
    key_quo <- rlang::enquo(key_col)
    value_cols <- unname(tidyselect::vars_select(names(data),!!!val_quos))
    key_col <- unname(tidyselect::vars_select(names(data),!!key_quo))

    n_val <- length(value_cols)
    result <- vector(mode = "list",length = n_val)
    id_cols <- setdiff(names(data),c(key_col,value_cols))

    for (i in seq_along(result)){
        result[[i]] <- spread(data = data[,c(id_cols,key_col,value_cols[i]),drop = FALSE],
                              key = !!key_col,
                              value = !!value_cols[i],
                              fill = fill,
                              convert = convert,
                              drop = drop,
                              sep = paste0(sep,value_cols[i],sep))
    }

    result %>%
        purrr::reduce(.f = full_join,by = id_cols)
}

> dat %>%
  spread_nq(key_col = grp,avg,sd,sep = "_")

# A tibble: 2 x 5
     id grp_avg_a  grp_avg_b  grp_sd_a  grp_sd_b
  <int>     <dbl>      <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>
1     1 1.3709584 -0.5646982 0.6569923 0.7050648
2     2 0.3631284  0.6328626 0.4577418 0.7191123
```

The change here is that we capture the unquoted arguments with `rlang::quos` and `rlang::enquo` and then simply convert them back to characters using `tidyselect::vars_select`.

Returning to the solution in the linked question that uses a sequence of `gather`, `unite` and `spread`, we can use what we've learned to make a function like this:

```
spread_nt <- function(data,key_col,...,fill = NA,
                      convert = TRUE,drop = TRUE,sep = "_"){
  key_quo <- rlang::enquo(key_col)
  val_quos <- rlang::quos(...)
  value_cols <- unname(tidyselect::vars_select(names(data),!!!val_quos))
  key_col <- unname(tidyselect::vars_select(names(data),!!key_quo))

  data %>%
    gather(key = ..var..,value = ..val..,!!!val_quos) %>%
    unite(col = ..grp..,c(key_col,"..var.."),sep = sep) %>%
    spread(key = ..grp..,value = ..val..,fill = fill,
           convert = convert,drop = drop,sep = NULL)
}

> dat %>%
  spread_nt(key_col = grp,avg,sd,sep = "_")

# A tibble: 2 x 5
     id     a_avg      a_sd      b_avg      b_sd
* <int>     <dbl>     <dbl>      <dbl>     <dbl>
1     1 1.3709584 0.6569923 -0.5646982 0.7050648
2     2 0.3631284 0.4577418  0.6328626 0.7191123
```

This relies on the same techniques from **rlang** from the last example. We're using some unusual names like `..var..` for our intermediate variables in order to reduce the chances of name collisions with existing columns in our data frame.

Also, we're using the `sep` argument in `unite` to control the resulting column names, so in this case when we `spread` we force `sep = NULL`.

Comment: Great idea, unfortunately it fails in my session with `Error in FUN(X[[i]], ...) : object 'key_col' not found` for your example. With `R version 3.3.1 (2016-06-21)`, `rlang_0.1.2`, `tidyselect_0.1.1`, `tidyr_0.7.2`, `dbplyr_1.1.0`, `tibble_1.3.3`

Comment: @Moody_Mudskipper Odd. They all run fine for me with 3.4.1, tidyselect 0.2.0, tidyr 0.7.1 and tibble 1.3.4.

Answer (score 3):

Spreading operations can also be done by unnesting a properly reformated table, here's an alternative using `tidyverse` :

```
# helper function that returns an horizontal one lined named tibble wrapped into a list
lhframe <- function(x,nms) list(setNames(as_tibble(t(x)),nms))
dat %>% group_by(id) %>%
  summarize(avg = lhframe(avg,grp),
            sd  = lhframe(sd,grp)) %>%
  unnest(.sep="_")

# # A tibble: 2 x 5
#      id      avg_a     avg_b      sd_a      sd_b
#   <int>      <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>
# 1     1 -1.7631631 0.4600974 0.7595443 0.5664884
# 2     2 -0.6399949 0.4554501 0.8496897 0.1894739
```

Unfortunately the following doesn't work:

```
dat %>% group_by(id) %>%
  summarize_at(vars(avg,sd),lhframe,grp) %>%
  unnest(.sep="_")
```

Answer (score 2):

Since tidyr version 1.0.0

```
tidyr::pivot_wider(data = dat, id_cols = id, names_from = grp, values_from = avg:sd) 
# # A tibble: 2 x 5
#      id avg_a  avg_b  sd_a  sd_b
#   <int> <dbl>  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
# 1     1 1.37  -0.565 0.657 0.705
# 2     2 0.363  0.633 0.458 0.719
```